# dynamically change html5 appcache file

Tags: html, html5-appcache

Here's my problem.

I am working on a web application and want to use HTML5 AppCache feature to cache files on client side.

To do that i add reference to appcache file in manifest tag of HTML.

Now, what i want is to manage multiple appcache files on the server with different version and allow user to update if and when they require.

So, when user will launch an application i want to check if there is a newer version of appcache (so server will have 2 different files say v1 and v2 with v1 mentioned in manifest tag) available and if so, ask user if they want to update if so, then update cache with this new version(v2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers will already check for a new version of the manifest every time the app starts, there's no need for you to implement it yourself, it's the default behaviour.

If you want to have explicit control over the downloading of updates use the [Application Cache API](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html#application-cache-api) in your app and hook into the events where you want to provide a UI for the user.

Comment: i tried cancelling the updates but that does not seem to work. Below is the code which i tried.

 window.applicationCache.addEventListener(
           'checking',
           function (event) {
               event.preventDefault();
           },
           false
       );

I even tried 'updating' and 'downloading' events but the application still caches.

Any pointers on this will be helpful.

Thanks